# some pages cannot be found in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am the beginner in wordpress. I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 Lts. I installed wordpress but i cann't open the `options-general.php` , `themes.php` , `update-core.php` , `plugins.php` and `themes.php pages` on the url from the wordpress dashboard. please let me know me... how can i go ahead. Here is the url that i hit enter 
http://localhost/wp/demo/wp-admin/themes.php

Here is the problem screenshot.[image]

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot or error mesage, a screenshot will reveal more.

Comment: Yes kumar i shared a screenshot that you have suggested me.

Comment: Ok, there can be many issues. So here are some things you may try
1. Make sure you are able to access your admin dashboard http://localhost/wp/demo/wp-admin/

2. Make sure your server is running

3. If everything above is working fine, try turning off your internet and then access your website

There can be many issues, but most probably your server may not be up and running. Just a guess

Comment: Thanks Kumar, all was OK during turned of Internet but it shows error in the Internet connection.